# Opera and datetime-local is not displaying value

Tags: html, opera

I have the following date value: "2013-05-02T11:00+10:00" that I would like to display in the datetime-local input field in Opera, however it is not displaying anything for me.

I have a simple test page to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dtL" value="2013-05-02T11:00:00+00:00" />
    <br />
    <input type="datetime" name="dt"        value="2013-05-02T11:00:00+00:00" />
</body>
</html>
```

[image: result]
The datetime input field works as expected, but not my datetime-local. Referring to the [w3](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#form.data.datetime-local-def) docs, it does appear that I am doing the right thing. Does anyone have any idea what else I could do, or need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local times shouldn't use an offset:

```
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dtL" value="2013-05-02T11:00:00" />
    <br />
    <input type="datetime" name="dt"        value="2013-05-02T11:00:00+00:00" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what happens if you stare at dates for too long on different issues, you miss small details. Appreciate it.